# Wordpress Wp-login.php 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress

I have run into a bit of a weird problem on a site i created a couple of years ago. No new plugins have been added recently or anything else changed on the site for the last 6 months. Besides from the site admins adding content to the page.

But now, they cant acces the wp-login page. They just get a blank page and a 500 error.

I have looked around the web for some solutions, and have tried the most common ones i come accros:

- Tried turning plugins off.
- Tried changing the theme to default.
- Tried deleting .htcacces file.
- Checked if the wp-login.php was updated as to the wordpress codex

Some people have reported that they could acces the login page, by trying to access a specific wp-admin page and then get redirected. This does not work for me either.

None of the solutions above gave any results, so i am now at a bit of a loss.

The frontend of the site is working just fine btw.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does php error log says?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the PHP memory limit? 
you did not mention it and maybe it could help

1. Create a file called php.ini
2. Paste `memory=64MB` in there.
3. Upload it into your `/wp-admin/` folder using FTP

If this answer helps you. it's a memory issue and you need to figure out what takes your PHP memory limit.

Comment: Will give it a go :) ty